# Collinearity in Enumerations of the Rationals

Tags: euclidean-geometry, integer-sequences

I am looking for a solution of the [No Three-in-a-Line problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-three-in-line_problem) for the whole $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ plane and had the idea, to use a non-redundant enumeration of the rationals, like the breadth-first enumeration of the knots in the [Stern-Brocot tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern-Brocot_tree) or the [Calkin-Wilf tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin-Wilf_tree).

> **Question:**
>
> if an infinite sequence of points in $(x_i,y_i)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to the sequence of rationals generated by one of their enumerations $\frac{x_i}{y_i}$ (as mentioned above), which of those points $(x_k,y_k)$ have the property, that they are
>
> - collinear with $(x_i,y_i)$ and $(x_j,y_j)$, where $i\lt j\lt k$
> - the ones, that are collinear with exactly one of the pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ and $(x_j,y_j)$ for $i\lt j\lt k$?

Comment: And what is the "No three in a LIne" Problem on the entire $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ plane?

Comment: @fedja it is a maximal set of points with integer coordinates, that are not collinear with a pair of different points, that both have strictly smaller distance to the origin.